# Managing unused data in data driven redux apps

Tags: reactjs, redux

imagine a data driven app like a hotel management software implemented in react redux, now we have multiple pages like users, check-ins, services, invoices etc.

while opening each page data is loaded from API and stored in redux store, so my question is what are common design patterns to handle previously fetched data when navigating to a new page, you obviously don't need users when navigating to invoices as invoices API provides minimum user info associated with each invoice.

- So should we unload users in store in `ComponentWillUnmount` as we navigate to invoices?
- Should we leave the data in store?
- Should we use a single array to hold our data and overwrite it every time?

What are some best practices according to your experience?

Answer (score 0):

> What are some best practices according to your experience?

Generally, we can always follow these [guidelines](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide) as rules.
Everything will fall in place.

> Should we use a single array to hold our data and overwrite it every
> time?

If you have some data like invoices which is not too complex, that also need to be listed but not frequently updated, using array will work fine. we also can use [selectors](https://medium.com/@matthew.holman/what-is-a-redux-selector-a517acee1fe8) or utilities,
to select specific invoice and update component.

In case, if we have data that is frequently updated or has nested list then it is recommended to make it flat (normalise). Here is a [detail read](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape) :

Assuming invoices are frequently updated ? we can keep map of invoices

```
{ 
    "invoiceId1" : {},
    "invoiceId2" : {}
}
```

> So should we unload users in store in ComponentWillUnmount as we
> navigate to invoices?,  Should we leave the data in store?

It depends on use case. Let say if we have one single (route) or page component adhere's to both

- Complex data
- Total independent data

Then It is recommended to clear it up, else it should be good. however in redux,if we are normalising the store then it should not be a problem.
Please go through this [FAQs](https://redux.js.org/faq/performance) related to redux-performance, it will provide clarity on memory management in Redux.